# Unable to acquire JDBC Connection Keycloak Server

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I’ve been trying to connect Keycloak Server with an external Database. I’m following this URL https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/user-storage-jpa. The only difference I’ve made is changed the Database from H2 to Oracle. I added the ojdbc8.jar and module.xml in Keycloak Server and also added the datasource in standalone.xml

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/XAOracleDS" pool-name="XAOracleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</connection-url>
    <driver>oracle_driver</driver>
    <security>
         <user-name>system</user-name>
         <password>root</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
 <drivers>
         <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
              <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
         </driver>

         <driver name="oracle_driver" module="com.oracle">
           <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
         </driver>
 </drivers>
```

I’m getting an exception while login to Server.

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@60e25ab0[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@524e494f connection handles=0 lastReturned=1595844984722 lastValidated=1595844928474 lastCheckedOut=1595844984714 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@452982c2 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@44ed6e53[pool=XAOracleDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@797e6177[connectionListener=60e25ab0 connectionManager=5ef48439 warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/XAOracleDS] txSync=null]
15:46:24,754 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-1) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component EjbExampleUserStorageProvider for method public org.keycloak.models.UserModel org.keycloak.quickstart.storage.user.EjbExampleUserStorageProvider.getUserByUsername(java.lang.String,org.keycloak.models.RealmModel): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:215)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:376)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:156)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:627)
        at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
        at org.keycloak.quickstart.storage.user.EjbExampleUserStorageProvider$$$view1.getUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
        at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.getUserByUsername(UserStorageManager.java:405)
        at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getUserByUsername(UserCacheSession.java:257)
        at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.findUserByNameOrEmail(KeycloakModelUtils.java:213)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.getUser(AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.java:154)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.validateUserAndPassword(AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.java:127)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.validateForm(UsernamePasswordForm.java:55)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.action(UsernamePasswordForm.java:48)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processAction(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:155)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticationAction(AuthenticationProcessor.java:936)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processFlow(LoginActionsService.java:311)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processAuthentication(LoginActionsService.java:282)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticate(LoginActionsService.java:266)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticateForm(LoginActionsService.java:339)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:535)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:424)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:385)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:91)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
        at org.keycloak.quickstart.storage.user.EjbExampleUserStorageProvider.getUserByUsername(EjbExampleUserStorageProvider.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:197)
        ... 115 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2082)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1990)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2787)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2770)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2604)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2599)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2243)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1069)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
        ... 145 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@60e25ab0[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@524e494f connection handles=0 lastReturned=1595844984722 lastValidated=1595844928474 lastCheckedOut=1595844984714 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@452982c2 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@44ed6e53[pool=XAOracleDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@797e6177[connectionListener=60e25ab0 connectionManager=5ef48439 warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/XAOracleDS] txSync=null]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:159)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
        ... 164 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@60e25ab0[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@524e494f connection handles=0 lastReturned=1595844984722 lastValidated=1595844928474 lastCheckedOut=1595844984714 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@452982c2 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@44ed6e53[pool=XAOracleDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@797e6177[connectionListener=60e25ab0 connectionManager=5ef48439 warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/XAOracleDS] txSync=null]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:1055)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:792)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
        ... 168 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000461: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:571)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:977)
        ... 170 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: Error enlisting resource in transaction=Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a86301:-25b193d3:5f1ea93e:60 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.checkEnlisted(TxConnectionListener.java:957)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:394)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:564)
        ... 171 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Failed to enlist
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:1001)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:379)
        ... 172 more
```

I don’t know what I’m missing in the Datasource tag. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add an xa-datasource and following configuration worked for me.

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/XAOracleDS" pool-name="XAOracleDS">
       <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
             jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
       </xa-datasource-property>
       <driver>oracle_driver</driver>
       <xa-pool>
             <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
             <no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>
       </xa-pool>
       <security>
             <user-name>system</user-name>
             <password>root</password>
       </security>
       <validation>
             <valid-connection-checker 
               class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
             <background-validation>true</background-validation>
             <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
             <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
        </validation>
</xa-datasource>
```

and for driver tag

```
<driver name="oracle_driver" module="com.oracle">
        <xa-datasource-class>
             oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
        </xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```